# Modal closing when load finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

It appears that when the JQuery modal finishes loading it closes. None of the alerts in my script are appearing. Why doesn't it stay open? Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="JS/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function () {
          dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              height: 600,
              width: 800,
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
                  Cancel: function () {
                      alert("Cancel Button")
                  }
              }

          });

          form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {
              alert("Submit");
              event.preventDefault();
          });

          $("#create-user").button().on("click", function () {
              dialog.dialog("open");
          });
      });
  </script>
```

-

```
<div id="dialog-form" style="display: none">
                <asp:Panel ID="AddReference" runat="server">
                    <form action=# id="form">
                        <asp:GridView ...>
                        <Columns>
                            ...
                        </Columns>      
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
                </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your code and placed it into a JSFiddle and the alerts fire for me.

Have a look at the fiddle to see it working:

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/u3z2auhk/1/)

Your issue could be caused by any number of things:

---

### 1) An incorrect reference:

Open your browser's developer tools (F12) and click on console. Any JS errors will be listed there. I'm sorry if this is basic but from your example you are linking to jQueryUI but there is no reference to jQuery. You have to have both to work and if jQuery is referenced incorrectly, in the JS console you will see:

```
$ is undefined.
```

---

### 2) Incompatible Versions:

If it is not a reference error, make sure that you have a stable version of jQuery and jQuery UI. (The latest version of jQuery UI (v1.11.0) requires jQuery 1.6+ for example)

---

### 3) A Postback:

If you are using a hyperlink to trigger the dialogue, you need to cancel the dialogue's default action using either:

**Prevent Default:**

```
$("#create-user").button().on("click", function (e) {

    //somecode

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**or Return False:**

```
$("#create-user").button().on("click", function () {

    //somecode

    return false;
});
```

**Please note:** In the fiddle example I have changed the width and the height of the dialogue so it fits into the output pane.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't think of putting it into a fiddle. I had JQuery 2.1 included higher up in the code. Nothing is coming back as an error in the console or network log, but I'm starting to think the problem may be with the data the modal contains

Comment: You could try stripping it out and taking it back to it's most basic like I did in the fiddle. Hopefully through the process of elimination you can establish what the cause is.

Comment: Out of interest, you're not posting back are you? i.e. triggering your diaglogue with an anchor tag? which returns true? If you are make sure you put return false in your button click event as per my edited answer above. This will prevent it from posting back.

Comment: Excellent! You were right, it's the postback. I didn't see your comment about including the false in the click event.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make the return false option clearer. If you are happy with it please consider accepting it and upvoting so others can see what was causing your issue and therefore learn from it.